# tigervncsession service won't start, deletes password file

Tags: vnc

On Ubuntu 22.04, I'm using TigerVNC (via the `tigervnc-standalone-server` package) to provide remote desktop access to a headless server.

For one user, the `tigervncserver` service exits with no diagnostic message:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart tigervncserver@:2
$ sudo systemctl status tigervncserver@:2
○ tigervncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tigervncserver@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver tigervncsession[14835]: pam_unix(tigervnc:session): session opened for user user2(uid=1002) by (uid=0)
Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver tigervncsession[14835]: tigervncsession: tigervncserver exited with status=1
Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver tigervncsession[14835]: pam_unix(tigervnc:session): session closed for user user2
Jul 14 18:31:53 myserver systemd[1]: tigervncserver@:2.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Even though `tigervncserver` exits with status 1 the overall service does not show as failed.

In `~user2/.vnc/hostname:2.log`, it looks like it's asking for a password, which fails because it's running as a service and can't receive input:

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

getpassword error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Password:
```

I *do* have a `~user2/.vnc/passwd` file, but bizarrely it's being deleted when the service tries to start:

```
[pid 15789] unlink("/home/user2/.vnc/passwd") = 0
[pid 15789] write(1, "\nYou will require a password to "..., 55) = 55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is implemented in `/usr/share/perl5/TigerVNC/Wrapper.pm`:

```
# Make sure the user has a password.
sub CreateVNCPasswd {
  my ( $options ) = @_;

  my $passwordArgSpecified =
    ($options->{'src'}{'vncPasswdFile'}//"undef") eq "cmdline";

  # Check whether VNC authentication is enabled, and if so, prompt the user to
  # create a VNC password if they don't already have one.
  return if !$options->{'vncAuthEnabled'} || $passwordArgSpecified;
  my $vncPasswdFile = $options->{'vncPasswdFile'};
  my $st = stat($vncPasswdFile);

  if (!defined($st) || ($st->mode & 077)) {
    print "\nYou will require a password to access your desktops.\n\n";
    unless (unlink($vncPasswdFile) || $! == ENOENT) {
      print STDERR "Can't remove old vnc passwd file '$vncPasswdFile': $!!\n";
      exit 1;
    }
    system(getCommand("tigervncpasswd"), $vncPasswdFile);
    exit 1 if (($? >> 8) != 0);
  }
}
```

The culprit is the check `$st->mode & 077` which is testing if the password file has any permission bits set for anyone other than the owner---i.e., the password is unsafely stored on disk.

Because I was creating my password file with:

```sh
echo "$PASSWORD" | tigervncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd
```

The default permissions of the file were `-rw-rw-r--`. We can create the file with `-rw------` permissions:

```sh
SAVED_UMASK=$(umask)
umask 177  # Limit permissions to -rw------
echo "$PASSWORD" | tigervncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd
umask "$SAVED_UMASK"
```

Or just `chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd`.